# Unexpected result from `Between`

Tags: bugs

**Bug introduced in 12.3 or earlier and persisting through 14.0 or later**

---

The documentation mentions that `Between` assumes the pair is sorted: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Between.html

They give the following examples:

```
Between[3, {2, 5}]
```

which is expected to return `True`

and

```
Between[3, {5, 2}]
```

which they claim returns `False`. But when I run this code I get `True` in both cases.

I am running Mathematica 12.3

Comment: Interesting.  On my installation of 12.3, `Between[3, {5, 4}]` returns `False`;   and `Between[x, {5, 2}]` returns `2 <= x && x <= 5`.  It appears that some auto-sorting is happening in the second argument if it contains numerical arguments.

Comment: Oh yeah, `Trace` gives me: `{{Interval[{5,2}],Interval[{2,5}]},Between[3,Interval[{2,5}]],True}`

Comment: And `Interval[{5,2}] == Interval[{2,5}]` evaluates to `True`!

Comment: What is your question? Please do not report bugs here. This site is not affiliated with Wolfram. If you are sure you found a bug (as you seem to be), contact Wolfram Support. Also, please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when asking new questions. See the tag description for the reason.